# Multiple Samples Without Replacement in R

Tags: r, random, subset

I have a data set of roughly 20000 customers and some assorted indicator variables.  I am trying to create 20 groups of 1000 unique customers.  My original thought was to take 20 samples without replacement, but I am finding it difficult to repeatedly sample.

This is the code I initially thought about but it requires me to repeat this process 20 times which seems very clunky.  Does anyone have thoughts about an easier way to create subsets of the data with no replacement?

```
set.seed(1)

sample1<-sample(fullindicators$customer_id,1000,replace=FALSE)

fullindicators$customer_id<-fullindicators$customerid[!(fullindicators$customer_id %in% sample1)]
```

Comment: If you feel an answer was helpful, in addition to upvoting, you can accept the answer. See stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You can sample your whole vector of ids (sample() has replace=FALSE as default):

```
sample1<-sample(fullindicators$customer_id)
```

Then split the sample in 20 equal sized groups to create a list of 20 groups:

```
split(sample1, rank(sample1)%%20)
```

if you mind the order of the individual values inside the groups, you may have to `sort()` the output of `rank()%%`:

```
split(sample1, sort(rank(sample1)%%20))
```

You can use this approach to split dataframes into lists of dataframes, as in:

```
#split the iris dataset into 15 groups after creating an artificial 'id' or 'index' column

iris$index<-1:nrow(iris)
split(iris, iris$index%%15)
```

If you just want to create an index column, you can easily just use something like

```
#create an index ("group") for 5 groups:
iris$group<-1:nrow(iris)%%5
```

Than you can use the "group" variable in your analyses

Comment: How then would I go about using that data in future functions.  I guess I am just struggling to take that list and convert it into a usable data frame.  I have tried something like